# ORA-00904: "TYPE": invalid identifier on trigger. Where have I gone wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-insert, database-trigger

I have created a table where the primary key auto increments. I have sent up the relevant data, sequences and triggers. But I have had no hope in executing an automated increment as of yet and my trigger keeps throwing errors.

Code:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE empid_seq
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 1101
NOCACHE;

CREATE TRIGGER empuser_trigger
before insert on empuser
for each row
begin
if :new.empuserid.nextval into :new.empuserid from dual;
end if;
end;
/


INSERT INTO empuser VALUES(empid_seq.nextval, 'James', 'Kirk', '+447911123456', '401', '203', (SELECT messageid FROM message WHERE messageid = '2101'));
INSERT INTO empuser VALUES(empid_seq.nextval, 'Spock', 'Spock?', '+447911123466', '401', '203', (SELECT messageid FROM message WHERE messageid = '2103'));
INSERT INTO empuser VALUES(empid_seq.nextval, 'Leonard', 'McCoy', '+447911144456', '401', '203', (SELECT messageid FROM message WHERE messageid = '2104'));
INSERT INTO empuser VALUES(empid_seq.nextval, 'Hikaru', 'Sulu', '+447911123856', '401', '203', (SELECT messageid FROM message WHERE messageid = '2106'));
```

What I want is for the ID to auto Increment on user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*comparison for the if statement has the main problem* which might be :

```
if <some condition> = <other condition> then 
 :new.empuserid := empid_seq.nextval;
end if;
```

And then you may try below :

Because there's only one candidate column as to be the `emp user id` is the first column of the table, it's understandable from the insert statement has no column listing for `empuser` table, then seems you're trying to set the `emp user id` by sequence with two ways

Get rid one of them :

remove

`:new.empuserid.nextval into :new.empuserid from dual;`, *i.e. remove trigger.*

or

`empid_seq.nextval,` inside insert statement, and transfer into the trigger as

`:new.empuserid := empid_seq.nextval;` by the way list all columns explicitly, except `empuserid` in the insert statement as `INSERT INTO empuser(col2,col3...) VALUES`. Convert these insert statements like

```
INSERT INTO empuser
SELECT empid_seq.nextval, 'James', 'Kirk', '+447911123456', '401', '203',
       messageid 
  FROM message 
 WHERE messageid = '2101'
```

Comment: Thank you, I got rid of my trigger which sorted the issue! But now when I try to input a record via apex I keep getting ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into empuser.empuserid. (I am inputting a value into this field), Do you know what the issue here could be? Im sorry for asking another question but I am really stuck.

Comment: @TheBiz welcome, it seems and expected that the id column is of primary type, so mandatory. You already use `empid_seq.nextval` inside insert statement, then there shouldn't raise such an exception. Please try again.

Comment: Correct. I am trying to input this on a master detail form within Apex. It will not auto increment my ID and if I manually put in a id on apex it will not accept that either. It will only accept id values which I pre-inserted onto my code (for example purposes). I am getting the error ORA-20505.

Comment: @TheBiz Did you try keeping the trigger, and remove the first component of insert statement (`empid_seq.nextval`)

Comment: @TheBiz `:new.empuserid.nextval` should be converted to `:new.empuserid := empid_seq.nextval` if trigger is kept.

Comment: I receive `ORA-04098: trigger 'USER.EMPUSER_TRIGGER' is invalid and failed re-validation` when I do those changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187793/discussion-between-barbaros-ozhan-and-thebiz).